# leaflet marker overlapping with polyline

Tags: leaflet, overlap

Is there a plugin (like OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) or does anyone know how to account for polyline overlapping with markers? I am basically trying to avoid situation line this [image: overlapping image]

**UPDATE1:**

I specifically want the polyline to go around the marker (like an arc) so that its clear to the user that the curved polyline is connecting the end-most markers and middle marker's polylines are then visible

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the issue with the above?  If it's a matter of the markers appearing below the lines, you just need to either

- add the markers after you add the lines
- or better yet, use leaflet's [.bringToFront()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtofront) and [.bringToBack()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtoback) methods.

Reordering the z index of a feature layer is a pretty straightforward use case, so I don't imagine you'd need a plugin for it.

Comment: I specifically want the polyline to go around the marker (like an arc) so that its clear to the user that the curved polyline is connecting the end-most markers and middle marker's polylines are then visible

Comment: Update your question with these details.